# Create correct expression with java

Tags: java, regex, operators, expression

I'm sitting on a problem and need your help. I have the following scenario:

I have three values:

```
boolean visible
int views
int executions
```

Now, I d'like to create a expression which sets `hidden` in my DB to true or false.

I should get this:

1. If visible is true, views <=4 or executions <=5 then `hidden = false`

My code looks like this:

```
calculateHiddenFlag(boolean visible, int views, int executions) {
    return visible && (views <=4 || executions <=5);
}
```

Can someone support me?

Unit tests:

```
    @Test
public void calculateHiddenFlag_false_if_hidden_false() {
    assertFalse(ImportHelper.calculateHiddenFlag(false, 0, 0));
}

@Test
public void calculateHiddenFlag_true_if_hidden_true_and_views_leq4() {
    assertTrue(ImportHelper.calculateHiddenFlag(true, 4, 0));
}

@Test
public void calculateHiddenFlag_true_if_hidden_true_and_executions_leq5() {
    assertTrue(ImportHelper.calculateHiddenFlag(true, 0, 5));
}

@Test
public void calculateHiddenFlag_false_if_hidden_true_but_views_gt4() {
    assertFalse(ImportHelper.calculateHiddenFlag(true, 10, 0));
}

@Test
public void calculateHiddenFlag_false_if_hidden_true_but_executions_gt5() {
    assertFalse(ImportHelper.calculateHiddenFlag(true, 0, 10));
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome. You can code it like you say it:
!(visible && views <=4 && execution <=5)

Comment: When you desribe the problem: "views <=4 **and** executions <=5 ", but when you write that into java code you use an **OR** all of a sudden:  `views <=4 || executions <=5`. You already wrote what you need down a line above. Change the or `||` to an and `&&`. And since you said "then hidden = false" you need to negate everything before returning it.

Comment: @g_bor I updated the question, there was a mistake

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS I updated the question - how should it look like?

Comment: you still can code it like you say it: now you are only missing the negation:
!(visible && (views <=4 || executions <=5))

Comment: You want to set the `hidden` flag "in my DB". Does this mean a relational DB like mySQL, ORACLE or similar? And if so, how do you access the DB? JDBC? Hibernate?

Comment: Your Unit tests are wrong. You specify `If visible is true, views <=4 or executions <=5 then hidden = false` meaning that `hidden = false` if the condition is true. Your last test `assertFalse(ImportHelper.calculateHiddenFlag(true, 0, 10));` should return true because `views<=4 and visible == true`

Answer (score 1):

(Edited according to comment below)

The initial statement should interpreted as

`if visible is true AND views <= 4 OR executions <= 5 then hidden = false`

and after adding parentheses to adhere to the [Precedence of Logical Operators](https://chortle.ccsu.edu/java5/Notes/chap40/ch40_16.html)

`if visible is true AND (views <= 4 OR executions <= 5) then hidden = false`

So the code would be literally what you say when reading it:

```java
calculateHiddenFlag(boolean visible, int views, int executions) {
    return !(visible && (views<=4 || executions<=5));
}
```

Or alternatively using some of [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#:%7E:text=In%20propositional%20logic%20and%20Boolean,a%2019th%2Dcentury%20British%20mathematician.) two times and removing parentheses according to [Precedence of Logical Operators](https://chortle.ccsu.edu/java5/Notes/chap40/ch40_16.html)

```java
calculateHiddenFlag(boolean visible, int views, int executions) {
    return !visible || views>4 && executions>5;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I made a mistake in my question - it should be `views <=4 OR executions <=5` not and.

Comment: Plus one for mentioning De Morgan's laws

Comment: This answer doesn't work for me. I have some Unit tests and they are failing. I've added them to the question

Comment: Either your Unit tests are wrong or the thing you're trying to accomplish is phrased wrongly; see my comment above